# Is there an R package to train regression models that return probabilistic forecasts instead of point forecasts?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, forecasting, tidymodels

I need to train a regression model able to estimate the full predictive distribution instead of a point forecast estimates.

Is there any package for R to do this? I usually use the tidymodels framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R function `predict` does exactly this for a linear model. Note that a linear model assumes a normally distributed response, but as the variance is estimated form the data, the prediction estimated from the data follows a t-distribution. You thus need, for given predictor values `x`, estimators for the mean value `μ̂(x)`, the standard deviation `s(x)` and the degrees of freedom `df`, all of which are computed by `predict.lm`:

```
# train model on data
fit <- lm(waiting ~ eruptions, faithful)
# prediction for new predictor value 10 
p <- predict(fit, data.frame(eruptions=10), se.fit=TRUE)
mu <- p$fit
# beware that s^2 is a combination of error of mu and of the residual sd
s <- sqrt(p$se.fit^2 + p$residual.scale^2)
df <- p$df
```

Then the probability density value of the response (prediction) at point `r` is

```
dt((r-mu) / s, df=df)
```